# magento2 knockoutjs custom template binding

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I'm trying to understand knockoutjs in magento2.especially custom template binding.I'm not able to get idea flow of rendering this.

Can any one have idea how it works?
atleast Where can I find definition of getTemplate?

```
<!-- ko if: (!quoteIsVirtual) -->
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customer-email') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        <!--/ko-->
```

Comment: Here is detailed explanation about knockoutjs in Magento 2 http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-ui-knockoutjs-using-container-less-ko-template-gettemplate

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Open

```
Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

file. look at  following line

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping</item>
```

So

```
Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js
```

this is your js file. Open it. Look

```
template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping'
```

this is the template file for this JS.

Go back to

```
Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

line 122 (M2 2.0.0-rc)

```
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
```

here you can see some child node. like

```
<item name="customer-email" xsi:type="array">
----
---
</item>
```

So

```
getTemplate()
```

is responsible for current template rendering that means

```
Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/form/element/email.html
```

Open it, then you can see following code snippet

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-login-form-fields') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
```

this 'additional-login-form-fields' node is the child node of 'customer-email' .

For your code snippet, if quote is not virtual then pick ko

```
foreach: getRegion('customer-email')
```

which is child node name and render its template.

Comment: getRegion('customer-email') means <item name="customer-email" xsi:type="array">. Is it correct? i mean it will iterate child nodes of that.

Comment: its render only current template. I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for your response.so many times in xml ..core team using  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item> .so which js file consider in this case?

Comment: yes. look following file Magento/Ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js . here uiComponent is declare as js.

Comment: How to get Site URl, Checkoutpageurl in any of the knockout template ?

Comment: Could they make it more complicated?

Comment: Why every time we are using foreach to get the template

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but i dont understand the getRegion() part. What does it do?
How does it call for a template?

Answer (score 1):

You can find defination of getTemplate from,

```
`root\vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\lib\core\element\element.js`
```

file from line no. 255 to 257.

```
  getTemplate: function () {
                return this.template;
            }
```

Comment: above code based on magento 2.0.0 general availability.