# Magento 2 knockout template rendering via getTemplate

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I have been checking out M2's frontend structure and I stumbled in some knockoutjs's template binding, for example in `Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/form.html`(this file render the add new address popup form in Shipping page of checkout), we got:

```
<form class="form form-shipping-address" id="co-shipping-form" data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')}">
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-fields') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
<div id="shipping-new-address-form" class="fieldset address">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-fieldsets') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
    <!-- ko if: (isCustomerLoggedIn) -->
    <div class="field choice" data-bind="visible: !isFormInline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="shipping-save-in-address-book" data-bind="checked: saveInAddressBook" />
        <label class="label" for="shipping-save-in-address-book">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Save in address book'"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

I understand the checkbox part, but not the `<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->`. I tried deleting one of those and the popup is empty. What is `getTemplate()` exactly and where can I find the piece of code that it references to?

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89492/magento2-knockoutjs-custom-template-binding

Answer (score 2):

Hi [Joel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/31559/joel)!

Regarding the following statement:

```
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
```

This is utilizing Knockout's [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) functionality to render the template specified by the JavaScript component's `getTemplate()` directive.

The `getTemplate()` directive is defined in [Magento's `uiElement` JavaScript module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/core/element/element.js) (mapped with RequireJS to `Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element`).

```
'uiElement': 'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element'
```

#### Other Resources

- [Magento 2 DevDocs: About the uiElement Class](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_uielement_concept.html)
- [KnockoutJS: Template Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)