# How to use knockout js in custom theme

Tags: magento2

Can anyone tell how can we use knockout js within custom theme's phtml file with any simple example?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89492/magento2-knockoutjs-custom-template-binding, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103861/how-to-use-knockout-js-within-magento-2, http://inchoo.net/magento-2/knockout-js-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Magento's native mini cart portion to check usage of knockout JS. This is very simple example of knockout JS.